# Casio fx-82MS: n-th logarithm

Tags: logarithms, calculator

I have got a [Casio fx-82MS](http://edu.casio.com/products/standard/fx82ms/) calculator, and I want to calcuate various logarithms with it, especially $\log₂(x)$-style logarithms. Unfortunately, its user interface contains buttons for just $\ln$ and $\log₁₀$.

How to do it with the existing set of buttons/commands?

Comment: Use change of base property of a logarithm?

Comment: $\log_a x={\ln x\over\ln a}$.

Comment: @Nunoxic, wow, is it possible? I'll search this function. David Mitra, your solution is great for me.

Answer (score 6):

According to [David Mitra](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/18986/david-mitra), $\log_a x={\ln x\over\ln a}$, what is absolutely usable for me.

Comment: You could also use $\log_a x=\dfrac{\log_{10} x }{\log_{10} a }$ if you prefer (or accidentally press the wrong log button)